# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на `.sendmailOn`, `.feedbackOn` не отрабатывала функция `getWindow()`

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста допилить скрипт
Нужно чтобы при нажатии на `.sendmailOn`, `.feedbackOn` не отрабатывала функция `getWindow()`

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

  function cookies() {
    alert ('click');
    $.cookie('smartCookies', true, {
        expires: 31,
        path: '/'
      });
    }

 $('.sendmailOn, .feedbackOn').on('click', function(event){
        cookies();
      }
    );

  (function($) {
    $(function() {

      if (!$.cookie('smartCookies')) {
        function getWindow() {
          $('.offer').arcticmodal({
            closeOnOverlayClick: true,
            closeOnEsc: true
          });
          $('#mark').addClass("good");
        };

        $('html').mouseleave(function(e) {
          if ((e.clientY < 0) && !($("#mark").hasClass("good"))) {
            getWindow()
          }
        });

      }
      cookies();

    })
  })(jQuery)

  $('.fff').submit(function() {
    if (!$(this).find('input:checked').length) {
      alert('Выберите один из вариантов');
      return false
    }
    cookies();
  }).find('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('input:text').prop('required', this.checked).attr('placeholder', this.checked ? 'Напишите комментарий' : '')
  });
});
```

Comment: Как вы думаете, много ли человек будут искать решение этой же проблемы по запросу «Помогите допилить js скрипт»? Сколько из них смогут найти?

Comment: Я сам долго думал, как назвать, в поле написано В чем заключается вопрс? Будьте конкретны. Я просто не знаю как назвать заголовок по другому, напишите как назвать,переименую. Спасибо!

Comment: к сожалению, я почти не знаю JS. А имена функций из второго предложения стандартные или вы их сами придумали?

Comment: Честно? Я сам не знаю что там написано)

Comment: То есть вы просто нашли какой-то код и пришли сюда за тем, чтобы вам его переписали? )

Comment: В данном коде эта функция и не вызывается. вызывается cookies

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можно сделать через флаг

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var flag = true
 $('.sendmailOn, .feedbackOn').on('click', function(event){
        var flag = false
      }
    );
  (function($) {
    $(function() {
      if (flag)
      {
        function getWindow() {};
      }
      var flag = true
    })
  })(jQuery)
});
```

Comment: Раз вы понимаете смысл задачи, переформулируйте заголовок вопроса, пожалуйста.